# Excel Macro - Unlock, Spellcheck, Lock

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that needs to unlock all the sheets in a workbook, run the spell checker, and lock all the sheets (with the original column/cell formatting allowed). The locking errors out each time and I can't figure out why.

I know this doesn't include the formatting aspect, but here's what I've got.

```
Sub SpellChecker()

'unprotect all sheets
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(i).Unprotect "Password"
Next i

'select all sheets
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Sheets
    If ws.Visible Then ws.Select (False)
Next

'run spellchecker
Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=2).Execute

'protect sheets  
For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(i).Protect "Password"
Next i

'selects one sheet/deselect all
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error. And it highlights the "sheets(i).Protect "Password" row.

Comment: You're getting the error I believe because you have multiple worksheets selected.  AFAIK, there's no reason to select all of them, what's the purpose of selecting multiple sheets at once?  If you comment out that part, you'll see the `.Protect` line works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the point of protecting the sheets, you still have all the sheets selected.

Select just one before

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Select

'protect sheets
For I = 1 To Sheets.Count
    Sheets(I).Protect "Password"
Next I
```

---

However, perhaps doing them one sheet at a time is an idea..?

```
Sub SpellChecker()

    For Each ws In Sheets
        If ws.Visible Then
            ws.Unprotect "Password"
            ws.Select
            Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=2).Execute
            ws.Protect "Password"
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: This should work, but OP should consider why they're selecting multiple sheets in the first place.  AFAIK, there's no need to given the code posted.

Comment: Because I was under the impression that spell check only runs on the active sheet, is that not the case?

Comment: I guess OP is selecting multiple sheets because they want the spellcheck to run on multiple sheets? No idea if that's necessary of course - but it makes sense given the way they're invoking the spell check.

Comment: One sheet at a time is doable on my end, but not great for my end user time-wise.

Comment: @moosebiz - you realise that the spellchecker does it one sheet at a time too though right, whether you select all sheets or not? My point is that instead of unlocking all, running on all, locking all, the routine just deals with one sheet at a time and the loop is a lot tidier to read. The time taken to run will be the same.

Comment: @CLR - I think your solution is best. I was originally thinking that the pause between sheets to lock and unlock would feel laggy to the end user but the delay is so slight that it's inconsequential. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that does *not* require that the Worksheets ever be unprotected - instead, it will change the Protection on Protected Sheets to allow VBA to edit cells (but *not* allow the User to edit them) - however, this requires `Range.CheckSpelling` instead of `Application.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=2).Execute`

```
Sub CheckAllSpelling()
    Dim CheckSheet As Worksheet, CheckRange As Range, CheckCell As Range, SheetVisible AS XlSheetVisibility
    'Loop through Worksheets in the Workbook
    For Each CheckSheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        'Allow VBA to edit a Protected Sheet, but not the User
        If CheckSheet.ProtectContents Then CheckSheet.Protect Password:="Password", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
        'Filter for Cells with Text to check
        On Error Resume Next
        Set CheckRange = CheckSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        On Error GoTo 0
        'If there are Cells to Check
        If Not CheckRange Is Nothing Then
            SheetVisible = CheckSheet.Visible
            'Loop through cells
            For Each CheckCell In CheckRange.Cells
                With CheckCell
                    'If there is a typo, show the cell and Spellcheck it
                    If Not Application.CheckSpelling(.Text) Then
                        CheckSheet.Visible= xlSheetVisible
                        CheckSheet.Activate
                        .Select
                        .Show
                        DoEvents
                        'This next line is to fix a bug when checking a single cell
                        CheckSheet.Range(.MergeArea.Address & ", " & .MergeArea.Address) _
                        .CheckSpelling
                    End If
                End With
            Next CheckCell
            CheckSheet.Visible= SheetVisible
        End If
        'Tidy up the Loop
        Set CheckRange = Nothing
    Next CheckSheet
    'Same message as normal Spellcheck
    MsgBox "Spell check complete.  You're good to go!", vbExclamation
End Sub
```

(Note the fix for a bug where checking a Single Cell will instead check the entire Sheet)

Comment: This didn't seem to work. The completion message popped up immediately without addressing known spelling errors.

Comment: @moosebiz Are these errors in Constants (which it will find), or in Formula (which it won't)?  And, is the Password for each protected sheet *definitely* "Password"?  I have tested this, and it seems to work on my computer

Comment: The errors are within actual cells, which have various formats (none of which are formulas). The password is definitely "Password" and is why I use macros to lock and unlock, so I don't misskey the password after typing it constantly.